# undefined symbol: __gnat_rcheck_CE_Invalid_Data when linking ADA with C++

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ada

I am linking some ADA object files with some C++ code, which calls ADA functions. Compilation and linking passes without any problem, but when I run the program, a runtime exception occurs:

```
undefined symbol: __gnat_rcheck_CE_Invalid_Data
```

It appears as if I forgot to link some object file. However, I am passing all .o files generated by the ADA compiler to the linker...

Any ideas?

Cheers

Michael

P.S.: I am deveveloping on (Ubuntu) Linux, GNAT 2014, gcc 4.7.4.

Comment: you will not be able to run your program if you haven't linked?  Do you mean you see this error at the linkage stage?

Comment: Linking works, I have edit the original post.

Comment: You could try building the Ada code as a library, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403353).

Comment: I built a (static) library (thanks for the excellent explanation by the way!) However, now I get ``undefined symbol: system__pool_global__global_pool_object`` when executing my C++ program. Any idea?

Comment: I only just saw your comment, because SO only notifies me about comments on **my** questions or answers unless the comment includes “@my-name”. Hope you’ve resolved it (by building a **dynamic** library, perhaps)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for following up! :) I've actually solved the problem, see my comment at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The reason was that I did not link the gnat-2014 library when I compiled the C++ program.

To all other newbies: Add `-lgnat-2014 -L<directory_to_libgnat-2014.so>` to the gcc options.

Eventually I followed Simon Wright's suggestion and compiled my ADA code into a (shared) library, works like a charm.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

Are you initialising the Ada RTS before calling any Ada functionality?

(assuming the main program is in C++)

If not, see [this simple example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/A-Simple-Example.html) of how to combine the two.

Essentially your C++ main program must call `adainit()` as part of its initialisation, to start the Ada runtime system, before calling any Ada code, then it should call `adafinal()` before exit, so that the Ada RTS can shutdown cleanly (e.g. finalise objects, release storage, terminate tasks etc)

In practice I find it easier to write the main in Ada and link in the C/C++ .o files and libs necessary. Ada tracks its own dependencies automatically so you only need to explicitly tell gnatmake (or gprbuild) about the C/C++ parts.

Comment: Yes, I am calling `adainit()` and `adafinal()`.

I have already successfully linked the same Ada code with a simple C++ program (consisting of only one object file) using gprbuild. Now I want to link this Ada code with a larger C++ program, which has a complex Makefile (thus, I thought it may be easier to have the main function in C++).

Comment: Second thought is ... you are using the same compiler version throughout? That is, you are using the gcc that is part of GNAT2014, and not bits of different installations?  On Debian I use gcc-4.9 and gnat-4.9 together but they may not have made it down to Ubuntu yet.