# Access Ada (in a .so) from Java JNI

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ada

I'm calling Ada code from a Java app in Linux.
The Ada code resides in a dynamic lib (shared-library) with a C-api.

Linking the .so from Java works. Likewise calling the C-functions in the .so and furthermore call the Ada code. But that's where it ends...

The call to Ada works fine, but it seems that Ada doesn't have a (secondary) stack. I know that a call to adainit() has to take place, either auto or manual.
I've tried a number of switches for the binder with no luck, it wont generate a 'b-*' file containing elaboration base code (and containg adainit() that is).

When building the .so I've also tried binding with -Dnn (like -D20k and -D10m) and also tried to call a task with the 'secondary_stack_size' directive. But the task itself won't be created due to no stack, neither static or dynamic creation works.

Is it impossible to call a ada-package from c in an '.so'?

Any ideas?

(CentOS 8.0, Gnat PRO 21.0)

Answer (score 4):

Try to build [stand-alone library](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#stand-alone-library-projects). This way it will initialize itself during the loading. Otherwise you need to call `adainit` yourself before the first call to an Ada function.

Comment: I wrote [an answer about creating a stand-alone library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14403353/40851).

Comment: Time has passed, but no luck... The problem is that there is no 'adainit' to call... As I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please note the lib has a 'c'-api. This due to that I want to use some ada code in a current .so that is coded in 'c'. I've build both .a and .so. For the .so I've linked it both static and dynamic. But of course with no luck due to the absence of secondary stack.